# Sorting SQL list by int

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, entity-framework-5

i'm fairly new to MVC and entity framework and I was hoping someone would be able to help me.

I have a SQL database that has a column that contains ints. I want to pull these values out and put them into an html.dropdownlistfor

I was originally trying to do:

```
List<SelectListItem> List = dbAccess.KeywordCorrelationData.Select(
temp => new {
    Value = temp.DefaultDestroyPeriod.ToString(), 
    Text = temp.DefaultDestroyPeriod.ToString()
}).OrderBy(temp => temp.Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

However this only sorted by the text value not numeric value.

I've since found a solution but it's a lot longer:

```
List<SelectListItem> List= new List<SelectListItem>();

List<int> tempIntList = dbAccess.KeywordCorrelationData.Select(temp => temp.DefaultDestroyPeriod).Distinct().ToList(); 

tempIntList.Sort();

foreach (int tempInt in tempIntList)
{
    int wholeYears = (int)Math.Round((double)tempInt / 365, 0);
    SelectListItem newItem = new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = tempInt.ToString(),
        Text = tempInt.ToString() + " days (approx. " + wholeYears.ToString() + (wholeYears == 1 ? " year)" : " years)")
    };

    List.Add(newItem);
}

return List;
```

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do it than this? I've googled and searched on here but can't find anything like it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `DefaultDestroyPeriod`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DefaultDestroyPeriod` is already of numeric type, just apply the ordering before you do the `Select`:

```
List<SelectListItem> List = dbAccess.KeywordCorrelationData
    .OrderBy(kcd => kcd.DefaultDestroyPeriod)
    .Select(kcd => new
    {
        Value = kcd.DefaultDestroyPeriod.ToString(), 
        Text = kcd.DefaultDestroyPeriod.ToString()
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I just tried this, it pulls out the data but it's not sorted into the correct order. And to answer your other comment `DefaultDestroyPeriod` is an int